# Compare two POJO objects in the same list using date property in Java 8

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have an Employee POJO class which has a property date. I have to compare the POJO objects and find out the Employee with the same name and latest date and collect to a different list.
I am trying to do it using Java 8's isBefore() and isAfter() methods but unsuccessful till now.

```
public class Employee {
       private LocalDate date;
       private String name;
}
```

```
Employee Objects:
  ["John", 2022-02-07]
  ["John", 2022-02-17]
  ["Mike", 2022-01-19]
```

It is a list of Employee Objects. So as per the task ["John", 2022-02-17] should be collected.

I can get the result using min/max and Comparator but trying to solve it using isAfter() and isBefore().

Comment: If you got it to work, why would you want to use `isBefore` or `isAfter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be an option:

```java
Map<String, Employee> map = employees.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(
        Employee::name,
        collectingAndThen(
            reducing((a, b) -> a.date.isAfter(b.date) ? a : b),
            Optional::get
        )
    ));
```

This is what happens:

First, we group by `name`, which results in a `name => list[date]` mapping. Then we reduce the list to get a single value, comparing each element of the list with dates to the subsequent one. The comparison is done with `isAfter`.

The `collectionAndThen(…, Optional::get)` part exists because `reducing` returns an `Optional<E>` rather than an `E`. But `groupingBy` guarantees us that each list contains at least one element.

Answer (score 0):

In order to execute this operation you have to follow these steps:

1. group by names having a `Map<String, List<Employee>>` as a result
2. reduce every `List<Employee>` to one `Employee`
3. select the employee that has the max date

```java
Map<String, Optional<Employee>> mapResult = employees.stream()
        .collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getName, // 1
                Collectors.reducing( // 2
                    BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getDate)) // 3
                )
            )
        );
```

Example input:

```
["John", 2022-02-07]
["John", 2022-02-17]
["Mike", 2022-01-19]
["Mike", 2022-03-17]
```

Example output:

```
["John", 2022-02-17]
["Mike", 2022-03-17]
```